# Unrecognized Arguments by Argparse despite error message showing arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python script that I am trying to pass arguments to from a bash script. The arguments are recognized when run in a run configuration in PyCharm, but when I run the shell script with the same arguments in a shell I get an `unrecognized arguments` error message.

The arguments are constructed and used like:

```
class BQJob:

    def __init__(self):
        self.parser: ArgumentParser = self.create_parser(__name__)
        self.args: Namespace = self.parser.parse_args()
        self.freq = self.args.freq
        self.n_periods = self.args.n_periods

    def create_parser(self, name):
        parser = ArgumentParser(name)
        parser.add_argument("--freq", help='Frequency of report, choose from "M", "D", "W".', action="store",
                            default=None)
        parser.add_argument("--n_periods", type=int, help='How many periods to analyze', action="store", default=None)
        return parser


class SomeJob(BQJob):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SomeJob, self).__init__()

    def run():
        # Here job is executed using the arguments passed in the BQJob Query Class
```

And the shell script is essentially:

```
#!/bin/zsh

cd $HOME || exit
PROJECT_DIR="$HOME/project_folder"
PROG="$PROJECT_DIR/src/python/jobs/python_job.py"
FREQ="W"
ARGS="--freq $FREQ --n_periods 1"
export PYTHONPATH="$PROJECT_DIR"
echo "PYTHONPATH: $PYTHONPATH"
python $PROG $ARGS 2>> "$PROJECT_DIR/logs/job_err.log" >> "$PROJECT_DIR/logs/job_out.log"
```

and when run I run the bash script I get:

```
usage: src.python.job_query [-h][--freq FREQ]
                            [--n_periods N_PERIODS]
src.python.job_query: error: unrecognized arguments: --freq W --n_periods 1
```

It shows the `--freq` and the `--n_periods` arguments in its list of expected arguments, but it still errors.

Comment: What happens if you don't store the args in a variable? That is, `python $PROG --freq $FREQ --n_periods 1`.

Comment: I just tried and still get the same message.

Comment: Can you post the code where `create_parser` is called?

Comment: It's getting `args` as one string.  It should be a list of 4 strings.  A regular script call would split this.

Comment: What is your configuration in pycharm?

Comment: @kmkurn I added the `create_parser` call to the original post. @hpaulj what would you consider a "regular script" in this context?

Comment: @drum I just put `--freq W --n_periods 1` in the parameters field in the run configuration — nothing else has been changed otherwise in the default run configuration window.

Comment: @hpaulj So it was getting parsed as one string and changing the script to:

`python $PROG "--freq" $FREQ "--n_periods" $N_PERIODS 1`

Is there a way to better handle this on the python side or a better practice to avoid this from happening?

Comment: Looks like this is a `zsh` issue, https://zsh.sourceforge.io/FAQ/zshfaq03.html.  It isn't splitting `$ARGS` into words as you want.  I found this with a quick web search  on `'zsh $var'`

Comment: It's not an "issue"; it's the documented default behavior of `zsh`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an *array* to store multiple command-line arguments.

```
#!/bin/zsh

cd $HOME || exit
project_dir="$HOME/project_folder"
prog="$project_dir/src/python/jobs/python_job.py"
freq="W"

args=(--freq $freq --n_periods 1)
export PYTHONPATH="$project_dir"
echo "PYTHONPATH: $PYTHONPATH"

python $prog $args 2>> "$project_dir/logs/job_err.log" >> "$project_dir/logs/job_out.log"
```

Ordinary parameters are not subject to word-splitting by default in `zsh`. (And if you *force* word-splitting, you are not guaranteed to preserve what you intended to be the original words in the result.)

Answer (score 0):

---

It turns out that comments by @hpaulj are correct and that `zsh` does not pass an `$ARGS` string with multiple arguments as multiple strings.

By splitting the args out like `python $PROG "--freq" $FREQ "--n_periods" $N_PERIODS` resolves the issue.

Comment: Didn’t you try this as I suggested in the comment and still get the same error? Also, there’s no `$N_PERIODS` variable in your question. Where did it come from?

Comment: @kmkurn All it needed was quotes surrounding the argument names to work. As for `N_PERIODS` I added that in after in my code after posting the initial question instead of hard coding `--n_periods 1` as I did in the initial post.